# c/c++ (VS2008) enclose macro param in quotes

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, c-preprocessor

For a lot of function calls in a C app that needs some degree of debugging I wanted to add a macro to ease the typing that I had to do.

right now I am calling a function like this:

```
aDebugFunction(&ptrToFunction, __LINE__, "ptrToFunction", param1, param2, etc)
```

So I thought lets write a macro that does the first 3 parameters for me, like this:

```
#define SOMEDEFINE(x) &x, __LINE__,  "x"
```

However, as most of you will immediately know, this won't work it won't replace "x" with the name that x has been given but will just pass "x" as 3rd parameter.

My knowledge of this preprocessor macro happening stuff is quite limited and thus my googling-ability is also quite useless due to not knowing where to search for exactly.

I hope one of you guys/girls could give me either a solution or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the `#` convert token to string command of the preprocessor. You should define your second macro this way:

```
#define SOMEDEFINE(x) &x, __LINE__,  # x
```

Or if `x` can also be a macro call, and you want the string to contains the expansion of the macro, you need to use an auxiliary macro:

```
#define TOKEN_TO_STRING(TOK) # TOK
#define STRINGIZE_TOKEN(TOK) TOKEN_TO_STRING(TOK)
#define SOMEDEFINE(x) &x, __LINE__, STRINGIZE_TOKEN(x)
```

For example, if you have the following code:

```
#define SHORT_NAME a_very_very_very_long_variable_name
SOMEDEFINE(SHORT_NAME)
```

Then, with the first macro, it will expand to

```
&a_very_very_very_long_variable_name, __LINE__, "SHORT_NAME"
```

While, with the second macro, it will expand to:

```
&a_very_very_very_long_variable_name, __LINE__, "a_very_very_very_long_variable_name"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do a lot better than that: `#define SOMEDEFINE( X, ... ) aDebugFunction( &(X), __LINE__, #X, __VA_ARGS__ )`

You could then simply call into this code like this: `SOMEDEFINE( ptrToFunction, param1, param2, etc )`
And that would effectively call: `aDebugFunction( &( ptrToFunction ), __LINE__, "ptrToFunction", param1, param2, etc )`